# Unity issue: "The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'EventSystem') is missing!"

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

Nice to meet you. I'm really a newbie with Unity and  I'm having lots of trouble with the EventSystem element of my scenes. I tried to looking for a solution for like...hours and I'm kinda lost.

The context: I was following a tutorial to create a dialogue system for my game, I created some UI elements so a Canvas and a default EventSystem were created too in the process.

My issue is that the EventSystem lost its script at a certain point and I get this alert "The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'EventSystem') is missing!".

The point is that Unity created this EventSystem for me when I created the Canvas and back thenI couldn't see the name of this Script [It looked like a default/generic script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCs1I.png).

Now I get this "none (Mono Script)" issue, but since I didn't put the default script there I don't know what I need to put there to make it work again.

[What I get now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Tco.png)

Any clues? Ty so much for the help :(.

I'm sorry if the explanation is a bit convoluted but I have little experience in the field.

I tried to deleted the Eventy System, The canvas, all the UI elements. Nothing changed

This happened several times during my training days. Now, even if I create a brand new scene in this project and I create a canvas too, the EvenSystem doesn't have the default script...and the missing alert pop up again and again.

Comment: so you need to ask yourself what you did.. so you did training? did you ask the trainer?  did you change some project settings perhaps related to input?

Comment: That means the script isn't compiled. You have a script compilation issue. Look into the logs and see if it tells you of any other more primary errors. If not, then restart Unity and maybe it compiled fine

Comment: This can happen if you leave unity in play mode and then make changes to scripts.  Once you tab back to unity, it compiles the script changes and any runtime references are lost and result in these warnings.  Stopping the editor is enough to resolve the issue (if this was the cause).

Comment: @hijinxbassist as soon as possible - first thing after installing Unity - you should switch to `compile after leaving play mode` :'D ... But no the message OP mentions is not a missing reference but rather a missing component.. meaning a script was removed .. or moved/renamed without solving all compiler issues

Comment: Did you by any chance tweak [Player Settings -> Active Input Handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B72mG.png) to support only the new Input System?